# How to open PDF in a new window if Firefox is not on the current desktop?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, virtual-desktop

I open PDFs with Firefox. If I open one on an empty Windows 10 desktop, but some other desktop has a Firefox window open, that window will open a new tab for my PDF and Windows will switch to it immediately.

I would like to open the PDF in a new window instead. But if there is a Firefox window on the *currently selected* desktop, I would like the PDF to open in a tab in that window.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening PDF files from Explorer or another application, then opening Firefox's `about:config` and setting:

```
browser.link.open_newwindow.override.external        2
```

should cause these files to open in a new window on the current desktop.  See [How to prevent firefox from opening new window/tab](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1190923) for discussion of related options.

With this setting, the only way I know to open a file from Explorer in an *existing* Firefox window is to drag the file onto the tab bar background or `[+]` button.  Or you could drag it onto an existing tab to open in that tab.